# How can I fix 'Module not found' errors in a React project using webpack and yarn?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/cookie-signature/index.js 5:13-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\satya\Desktop\GOD2\frontend\node_modules\cookie-signature'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
```

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/destroy/index.js 15:17-41
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\satya\Desktop\GOD2\frontend\node_modules\destroy'
```

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/destroy/index.js 16:13-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\satya\Desktop\GOD2\frontend\node_modules\destroy'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
```

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\satya\Desktop\GOD2\frontend\node_modules\etag'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
```

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/etag/index.js 21:12-31
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\satya\Desktop\GOD2\frontend\node_modules\etag'
```

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js 22:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Users\satya\Desktop\GOD2\frontend\node_modules\express\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
    - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "http": false }
```

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/request.js 19:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Users\satya\Desktop\GOD2\frontend\node_modules\express\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
    - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "http": false }
```

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js 20:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Users\satya\Desktop\GOD2\frontend\node_modules\express\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
    - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "http": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js 17:9-22
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\satya\Desktop\GOD2\frontend\node_modules\express\lib'


ERROR in ./node_modules/mime/mime.js 2:9-22
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\satya\Desktop\GOD2\frontend\node_modules\mime'


ERROR in ./node_modules/safe-buffer/index.js 3:13-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'buffer' in 'C:\Users\satya\Desktop\GOD2\frontend\node_modules\safe-buffer'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "buffer": require.resolve("buffer/") }'
    - install 'buffer'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "buffer": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/safer-buffer/safer.js 5:13-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'buffer' in 'C:\Users\satya\Desktop\GOD2\frontend\node_modules\safer-buffer'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "buffer": require.resolve("buffer/") }'
    - install 'buffer'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "buffer": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/send/index.js 22:9-22
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\satya\Desktop\GOD2\frontend\node_modules\send'
ERROR in ./node_modules/send/index.js 29:13-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\satya\Desktop\GOD2\frontend\node_modules\send'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/zlib/lib/zlib.js 1:0-43
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './zlib_bindings' in 'C:\Users\satya\Desktop\GOD2\frontend\node_modules\zlib\lib'
```

I have not written any errors in code but i am suddenly encountered this error please help me to overcome this error so please inform how to get rid of this webpack error and what is the reason of this error

One crucial element when asking a question about a webpack error is to provide all context related to your system and its configuration, which could be relevant to the issue. This will help others in understanding the specific environment of web pack output and compare with various CVEs and performance metrics.

When describing the problem, clearly state your expected outcome, and if possible, any previous resolutions to any similar issues. This will help to narrow down the possible causes of the error and guide others on where to focus in troubleshooting the issue.

It is also important to maintain a respectful and professional demeanor when asking a question about a webpack error. While it may be frustrating to encounter problems, maintaining a calm and collaborative attitude among all parties involved can help to resolve the issue in a more timely and satisfactory manner.

In summary, when encountering a webpack error, asking a question that includes detailed context, crucial information, expected outcomes, any previous resolutions, system and configuration information, and professional communication can help to pinpoint the cause of the issue and lead to a quicker resolution.